# error al abrir el pdf itext

Tags: java, itext

Estoy creando firma digital con itext pero cuando voy abrir el pdf me dice que el archivo esta dañado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public void firmarPdf(String origen, String destino) {



    try {
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                String pass = "456123789"; //PASSWORD DE LA KEYSTORE
                java.io.FileInputStream file = new java.io.FileInputStream(
                        "C:\\jks\\keystore.jks"); //EL ARCHIVO QUE GENERAMOS TIENE QUE ESTAR EN EL DISCO C
                keyStore.load(file, pass.toCharArray());
                PrivateKey pk = (PrivateKey) keyStore.getKey("mtorre4580",
                        pass.toCharArray());//USUARIO Y PASSWORD DE LA KEYSTORE
                Certificate[] chain = keyStore.getCertificateChain("mtorre4580"); //OBTENGO EL CERTIFICADO
                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(origen);
                FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destino);
                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper
                        .getSignatureAppearance();
                appearance.setReason("Firmar documento con itext mtorre4580");
                appearance.setLocation("Argentina");
                appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(72, 732, 144, 780), 1,
                        "signature");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Error al firmar el pdf");
            }
        }
```

Comment: puedes agregar el valor de la exception?

Comment: osea el hace todo el proceso bien pero al mometo de yo ver archivo pdf el acrobat me dice que no se puede abrir por que esta dañado

Comment: ¿Lo abre de alguna otra manera?

Answer (score 2):

me faltaba esto

```
ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
            ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, "SHA1", "BC");
            MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: Kevin, sería buena idea explicar que es lo que agregas y en que ayudo a solucionar el problema, podría ser de utilidad a otros desarrolladores! :)